# How to check if mouseenter an iframe in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure that it is possible, because I was able to do it using jQuery.

```js
$('iframe').mouseenter(function(){
    alert('jquery-work')
});

document.getElementById('iframe').addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
    alert('vanilla-js not prompt')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id=iframe src=http://www.bing.com></iframe>
Try to enter and leave the ifame<br>
I want the vanilla js to execute, but only js function execute
```

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at the above code, your jQuery call is not looking for an element with the ID of iframe but any iFrame element. If you add `id="iframe"` to your iframe, your vaniall code should work.

The equivilant to your bottom code in jQuery is actually

`$('#iframe') //element with the id of iframe`

`$('iframe') //Any iFrame elements`

`$('.iframe') //element with the class of iframe`

Here is answer:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
alert('vanilla-js not prompt')
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0uz19cmu/4/

Comment: Look in the JS fidle, the HTML element have ID iframe. This is not the question

Comment: The `addEventListener` call works in some browsers, and not in others.

Comment: Really? What does the underlying javascript in jQuery use? I thought addEventListener was the only way to add event listeners in JS. If that is true I'll remove my answer as I'd hate to direct people the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/0uz19cmu/3/

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].onmouseenter = function() {
    alert('vanilla-js not prompt');
};
```

This will only get the first `iframe` in the document. If you want to get a specific one, then I would recommend using an `id`.